# Laravel: How to make routes like /admin/customer/address and making filtering by customer possible

Tags: laravel, model, routes

I'm a little confused regarding laravel routes and how this should be done.

I have two models:

```
Customer
CustomerAddress
```

The relations are as one would expect:

```
Customer hasMany CustomerAddress
CustomerAddress belongsTo Customer
```

In my routes file I have this for the customer which is working perfectly:

```
Route::get('/admin/customers', 'Admin\CustomersController@index')->name('admin.customers.index');
Route::get('/admin/customers/create', 'Admin\CustomersController@create')->name('admin.customers.create');
Route::post('/admin/customers', 'Admin\CustomersController@store')->name('admin.customers.store');
Route::get('/admin/customers/{customer}', 'Admin\CustomersController@show')->name('admin.customers.show');
Route::get('/admin/customers/{customer}/edit', 'Admin\CustomersController@edit')->name('admin.customers.edit');
Route::patch('/admin/customers/{customer}', 'Admin\CustomersController@update')->name('admin.customers.update');
Route::delete('/admin/customers/{customer}', 'Admin\CustomersController@destroy')->name('admin.customers.destroy');
```

(I know I could use a resource route but I like the way this documents the available routes)

As for the customers addresses I would like to be able to use something like:

```
Route::get('/admin/customers/addresses', 'Admin\CustomersAddressesController@index')->name('admin.customers.addresses.index');
```

This wasn't working before and was returning a 404 but I eventually understood that it was because it was taking the "address" part and searching the database and since there wasn't a valid customer it returned me a 404. I fixed this by moving it to before the customers routes. Is this the correct way to do it?

I would also like to be able to filter the addresses by user id something like this:

```
Route::get('/admin/customers/{customer}/addresses', 'Admin\CustomersAddressesController@index')->name('admin.customers.addresses.index');
```

And return only the specific customer addresses but I'm not sure how this should be done.

Regarding the naming of the models, I have two migrations, one for a table named customers hence the Customer model and another one for a table called customers_addresses hence the CustomerAddress model.

Is this how it should be done?

It seems a little strange both models having Customer in the name but since the tables are like that this is what I did. Should I change the models names to just Customer and Address?

Should I also change the tables names to customers and addresses instead of customers and customers_addresses?

The same applies to the Controllers that are currently named CustomersController and CustomersAddressesController.

What is the correct name structure for this?

I know this is a lot but I'm really confused about this and I just want to get it done the right way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

firstly, regarding the naming convention, you are right. the naming can seem a little bit weird and long, but following the database administrative conventions, you are to name tables and columns with names closely relating to what they represent(1NF, First normal form Database rule).
 we need to always try to foresee and build an application which will be scalable. if you decide to change the table name of Customer_addresses, to simply address, this can cause a conflict in the future when you intend on adding various roles like, customerService, vendors, etc. if you intend on keeping their addresses in different tables for any specific reason, probably to reduce the numbers of queries and search  required to gather the result of addresses for a user of a certain role, you will face a naming conflict if you decide to rename the customer_address table to simply addresses.
note except you intend on gathering all addresses to a that table(which isnt recommended) then you can do that. also, a user can have more than one role, he/she can intend on using different addresses, so you might want to store them in their specific tables

Next for the route, i see you are trying to hide the customer details from the url when getting the customer addresses, you can do that by encrypting. 
you should use this.

```
Route::get('/admin/customers/addresses/{customer}', 'Admin\CustomersAddressesController@index')->name('admin.customers.addresses.index');
```

**but encrypt using the Crypt::encrypt. Your get link can be something like**

```
<a  href="{{route('/admin/customers/addresses',['customer' => Crypt::encrypt(customer_id) ])}}">Customers Address</a>
```

**Your controller**

```
public function getCustomerAddress($customer){    
    $customer_id = Crypt::decrypt($customer);    
    //then your action      
}
```

this will send an encrypted paramter through the url.
I my answer was able to help

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure about the naming but you helped me. As for encrypting, I never actually said anything about wanting to encrypt the customer details but thank you anyway.

Comment: you're welcome. you can upvote my answer to show it helped, and you can click the mark button below if my answer is accepted. thank you @Edd

Answer (score 0):

Before answer your question. I would like tell you I'm not good at English but I'm happy to share.

1. ​Your table name is fine, I will stick with it and no need to change to address because this table is belong to only for customer table.
2. about your controller name I would use single name not plural like you did.
   so CustomerAddressController instead of CustomersAddressesController.
3. About your route name file is fine. i will do the same as you did. because it's follow laravel document.
4. but for your route file. I prefer to use namespace and prefix instead of writing admin again and again.

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('customers', 'CustomersController@index')->name('customers.index');
});
```

for more you can read[Laravel Best Practice](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)

Thanks and hope it help

Comment: Thank you, I'll check Laravel Best Practive.